# Raid 1+0 on HP ML350 G5

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to setup a Proliant ML350 that has a SmartArray E200i Raid controller. I want to setup RAID 1 but there isn't any option for it, just 0, 1+0, and 5. I only want to use 2 drives since I just want to protect against hardware failure of 1 drive. The RAID controller allows me to select level 1+0 when I select the 2 drives. But as I understand, RAID 1+0 is RAID 10 and needs a minimum of 4 drives. Why isn't there an option for selecting RAID 1 on this controller for mirroring? Or is it that if I select RAID 1+0 it will mirror the drive without the the striping for performance? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HP SmartArray language, **RAID 1+0** means **RAID 1** when you *only* have two drives.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for but couldn't find it anywhere on HP's SmartArray guides.